# dispatch_async not working properly

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, asynchronous

i am capturing image in ios swift and try to save image and thumbnail image in background task

using this code

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), {

        var imageSaveCall = self.storeReceiptImageToFile(imageToSave,fileName:fileName)
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            println("Raw image saved")
        })

    })
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), {

        var imageSaveCall = self.storeReceiptThumbImageToFile(imageToSave,fileName:fileName)
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            println("thumb image saved")
        })

    })
```

it is working fine up to 4 time, after that it not even hitting the store image function. is there any mistake i am doing?

Comment: Some hints: Are you seeing those logs each time? It sounds like the queue is being blocked by something. If you pause the app in the debugger, what's happening on the background queue? Does it still fail if you make your own queue instead of using the system one? Does it fail if you only save the large image or the thumbnail, but not both?

Comment: Are you seeing those logs each time? NO , while first 4 time i can see, other time not, it fails all the small and big images after 4 times

Comment: I think that you should save ReceiptImage & Thumbnail in 2 different filenames.

Comment: The thread may be in a deadlock. As said above you should pause the execution and watching the thread stack. You may find a `trap` or something of this kind.